# Multiplying matrices by passing to function: Run-time check failure #2

Tags: c++

When running the program, an error pops up saying: 
Run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'B' was corrupted.

And another one pops up saying:
Run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'B' was corrupted.

If i ignore the messages and continue to run the program, I get these results:

163.4    51.26

125.7    94.83

140    63.28

136.028    370.056

Press any key to continue . . .

which rows 1-3 are correct, but the fourth row is not and i cannot figure out why.  Not sure if the error message has to do with the wrong result, or if it's a problem in my coding, but I've looked through the code and cannot figure it out.  Thanks for the help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int ROWSA = 4,
          COLSA = 3,
          ROWSB = 3,
          COLSB = 2;


void calc_AB(double [][COLSA], double B[][COLSB], double C[][ROWSA], int,        int, int);
void display_C(double [][ROWSA], int);

int main()
{


    double A[ROWSA][COLSA] = { { 5.2, 1, 9 },
                               { 3.6, 7.5, 0 },
                               { 8, 0, 4.4 },
                               { 0.1, 2.7, 10 } },
    B[ROWSB][COLSB] = { {12, 7.8},
                        {11, 8.9},
                        {10, 0.2} },
    C[COLSB][ROWSA];

    calc_AB(A, B, C, ROWSA, COLSB, COLSA);
    display_C(C, COLSB);

    return 0;
}

void calc_AB(double A[][COLSA], double B[][COLSB], double C[][ROWSA], int ROWSA, int COLSB, int COLSA)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWSA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLSB; j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < COLSA; k++)
            {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void display_C(double C[][ROWSA], int COLSB)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWSA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLSB; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << C[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `C`is declared as `C[COLSB][ROWSA];`, but the indexing `C[i][j]` uses the sizes in the opposite order.

Comment: *Run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'B' was corrupted.* -- Do not ignore this error.  Your program is basically worthless until you fix that error.

Comment: Also, using `std::array` instead of raw arrays, and usage of `at()`, you may have been able to solve the problem yourself [as this example shows](http://ideone.com/OcpxQt).  Note the runtime exception at the bottom of the page.  This is because `at()` threw an exception due to being out of bounds on the `i` component.

Answer (score 1):

> `C[COLSB][ROWSA]`

You made a mistake in the algebra, before in the coding.

the resulting matrix C should have the size `C[ROWSA][COLSB]`.

If you rewrite the code from there, it should be easy to fix it.